# UI Testing Failure

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode-ui-testing

Here is auto generated code. I didn't modified it.

```
func testExample() {

    let app = XCUIApplication()
    let defaultStaticText = app.tables.staticTexts["Default"]
    defaultStaticText.tap()
}
```

Error I got is:

> UI Test Activity: 
>   Assertion Failure: UI Testing Failure - Failure getting list of active applications: AX error -25205

Screenshot of the app:

[image: App screenshots displaying 1 app with screens. Table view with 3 options and sign up screen.]

All I did during the test is tapping on the Default row on top. I did this in Simulator. The error appears on the last line: `defaultStaticText.tap()`.

Comment: Is there an asynchronous task (i.e network data fetch) when you tap `defaultStaticText.tap()` before pushing your view controller?

Comment: No. It is initialising new view controller and then `navigationController?.pushViewController(authController, animated: true)`

Comment: Did you try to add an expectation that initially waits for the table view controller to have 3 cells?

Comment: No. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: `expectationForPredicate(NSPredicate(format: "count > 0"), evaluatedWithObject: app.cells, handler: nil)`
`waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(30.0, handler: nil)`

Comment: Got a new error now in addition to old one: `UI Test Activity: 
Assertion Failure: Asynchronous wait failed: Exceeded timeout of 30 seconds, with unfulfilled expectations:` "Expect predicate `count > 0` for object <XCUIElementQuery: 0x7fedb48312c0>".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use completely different names for “Default” and “Default configured”?
I think you get multiple cells for
`let defaultStaticText = app.tables.staticTexts["Default"]`

You can learn more from [here.](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/406/)

Comment: Yes, I solved my problem by renaming _Default Configured_ to just _Configured._